# merging 2 pdf with gofpdf

Tags: go, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

Did anyone work with pdf merger from gofpdi library?

I am trying to merge 2 pdf as one file. I pass them as reedseeker.

```
unc test(pdfm bytes.Buffer, m pdf.Maroto, pdf2 bytes.Buffer) {

    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")

    w, h := m.GetPageSize()

    importer := gofpdi.NewImporter()
    rs := io.ReadSeeker(bytes.NewReader(pdfm.Bytes()))
    tpl1 := importer.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, &rs, 1, "/MediaBox")
    pdf.AddPage()
    importer.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, tpl1, 0, 0, w, h)     
    
    importer2 := gofpdi.NewImporter()
    rs2 := io.ReadSeeker(bytes.NewReader(pdf2.bytes()))

    tpl2 := importer2.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, &rs2, 1, "/MediaBox")
    pdf.AddPage()
    importer.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, tpl2, 0, 0, w, h)

    err := pdf.OutputFileAndClose("pdfs/example.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error in generating the output pdf file: %w", err)
    }

}
```

As you can see tp1 and tp2 are imported from pdf1 and pdf2 so the final pdf should be merged. but in this case the final pdf has 2 page where both page contains the content of pdf2.

If i change the code to this,

```
func test(pdfm bytes.Buffer, m pdf.Maroto, pdf2 bytes.Buffer) {

    pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")

    w, h := m.GetPageSize()

    importer := gofpdi.NewImporter()
    rs := io.ReadSeeker(bytes.NewReader(pdfm.Bytes()))
    tpl1 := importer.ImportPageFromStream(pdf, &rs, 1, "/MediaBox")
    pdf.AddPage()
    importer.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, tpl1, 0, 0, w, h) 
    
    pdf.AddPage()
    importer2 := gofpdi.NewImporter()

    tpl2 := importer2.ImportPage(pdf, "test.pdf", 1, "/MediaBox")
    pdf.AddPage()
    importer.UseImportedTemplate(pdf, tpl2, 0, 0, w, h)

    err := pdf.OutputFileAndClose("pdfs/example.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("error in generating the output pdf file: %w", err)
    }

}
```

then the final pdf has 1st page as pdf1 and second page as pdf2 which is correct. As you can see i have changed the second pdf import as file instead of byte stream.

what am i missing here?

Comment: anyone have a solution to this? i tried the 2nd way, but its still duplicating the 2nd page

Comment: fyi, i solved this by reusing the same importer instead of creating a new importer "importer2" for the 2nd pdf